# Why use delete on a JavaScript object's getter and setter?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Why in these three cases,
I am curious what the difference of delete is or not and how it works internally.

1. described

```
var o = {
  set foo (val) {
    delete this.foo;
    this.foo = val;
  },
  get foo () {
    delete this.foo;
    return this.foo = 'something';
  }
};

o.foo = "test";
console.log(o.foo); // print 'test'
```

It looks like the value 'something' should come out, but 'test' is printed.
This is because getter is caching values.

2. but when not a using delete in getter

```
var o = {
  set foo (val) {
    delete this.foo;
    this.foo = val;
  },
  get foo () {
    return this.foo = 'something';
  }
};
o.foo = "test";
console.log(o.foo); // print 'something'
```

printed 'something'

3. lastly in a setter, when a delete not existed, throws RangeError maximum call

```
var o = {
  set foo (val) {
    this.foo = val;
  },
  get foo () {
    delete this.foo; 
    return this.foo = 'something';
  }
};

o.foo = "test";
console.log(o.foo); // print 'test'
```

Comment: Why would anyone use delete in a get? That would basically mean you have a const.

Comment: Your example 2 does not behave the way your question claims it does. The `console.log()` call prints "test".

Answer (score 2):

Let's go over these one by one:

1. `o.foo = "test";` is called, activating the setter. The setter deletes `this.foo`, deleting both the getter and the setter in the process. Then, `this.foo` is set to `"test"` by the second line, and now `o` is a normal object without any getters or setters.
2. I was not able to recreate this, it still prints `"test"` for the same reasoning as 1.
3. The setter does not have `delete` so when you try to call it, it runs `this.foo = val`, which calls the setter again, which calls the setter again, and it recurses infinitely, throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all!. I fully understood. What delete does and why the max call error occurs.

Why did you write delete?
This is to get rid of recalculating the value with getter when getting o.foo again. And simply get the value as the property of o, foo.
The important thing is that can intentionally use getters and setters for caching.